# rbind with partial column match?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, rbind

I have two dataframes of the following form

df1:

| first | second |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 7 |

df2:

| sec | fir |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 |

I'm trying to use `rbind` (or anything else that works haha) to merge the rows of these two dataframes by using a partial match on the column names (matching `first` with `fir`, and `second` with `sec`) to create a dataframe that looks like this

| first | second |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |

Thank you all in advance for the help!!!!

Comment: A suggestion: it is not the job of `rbind` to infer which columns should match which slightly-different columns. I think your challenge is to come up with a simple, robust *heuristic* that will match all of `x` (derived from `names(df1)`) to the closest of `y` (derived from `names(df2)`). Once you have figured that out, `rbind`ing the two frames is trivial, as akrun and RonakShah are demonstrating in their answers. More-robust heuristics might include some form of `stringdist`, which will likely be a much better guess than regexes or such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep` to find the column name in `df2` that is similar to one in `df1`.

```
cols <- sapply(names(df2), function(x) grep(x, names(df1)))
cols
#sec fir 
#  2   1
```

Using `cols` you can rearrange `df2`, make their names similar to `df1` and then `rbind`.

```
rbind(df1, setNames(df2[cols], names(df1)))

#  first second
#1     1      5
#2     2      6
#3     3      7
#4     4      3
#5     1      2
#6     3      1
```

Answer (score 2):

With `rbind`, it needs the columns to have the same name.  So, the option is to set the names of the second data with the names of the first one and then `rbind`

```
rbind(df1, setNames(df2, names(df1)))
```

---

If we need to automate by checking the substring, a distance based approach can be used

```
library(phonics)
nm1 <- c(names(df1), names(df2))
ind <- soundex(nm1, maxCodeLen = 2)
nm2 <- ave(nm1, ind, FUN = function(x) x[1])
rbind(df1, setNames(df2[match(ind[1:2], ind[3:4])], names(df1)))
```

Comment: thank you for this! is there a way to map specific column names to others? the column order in the two dataframes is slightly different so some specific assignment might be necessary